# MySQL update problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I am encountering error while updating my table field 'delete' in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `delete` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;

INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `delete`) VALUES('newa', 'no')
```

`UPDATE SET delete='yes`

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set delete-'yes'' at line 1
```

Comment: Using field names like "delete" is really not a good practice.  How about "deletable" or something like that?  Delete is a verb in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is a reserved word in mySQL.

You need to wrap the field name in backticks:

```
 SET `delete` = .....
```

or, preferably, use a different field name.

Comment: Thanks !! it really worked. i never realized that i have been using reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE student SET `delete`='yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the table name between UPDATE and SET.  You should have UPDATE student SET delete='yes'

Additionally, you shouldn't use reserved keywords as column names.

Comment: my bad ! but i have used table name while executing sql statement

Answer (score 0):

use `delete` instead of delete. Please do not use reserved words to name tables and columns. You might as well rename the column to `is_deleted`.